# Pydrake: set_realtime_rate not taking effect until end of AdvanceTo call: Is InitializationParams the answer?

Tags: python, drake

| drake 1.9.0 | python 3.7 | OS: ubuntu 20.04 | pycharm | Meshcat viz |

I have a kuka arm welded to world that I'm sending a cartesian trajectory to follow that's processed by a Differential Inverse Kinematics controller and a Inverse Dynamics controller.

When the simulation first starts, the arm moves at 400+% of the realtime rate, and it isn't until it hits the timestamp of my first AdvanceTo(t+0.1) call that it slows down to respect the set_realtime_rate() (0.1%) that I set before my Initialize() step.

I'd like my simulation to respect my set_realtime_rate() all the time if possible: could InitializeParams be used to set this? The documentation regarding what I can set in [InitializeParams is sparse](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/structdrake_1_1systems_1_1_initialize_params.html).

Here's my code:

```
# Set up the simulation
    simulator = Simulator(diagram, context)
    simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(0.10)
    simulator.Initialize()

    # Add a button to start the simulation
    start_sim_button = 'Start Simulation'
    meshcat.AddButton(start_sim_button)

    # Wait until the start button is pressed before beginning the simulation
    print(f'Press the \'{start_sim_button}\' to start the simulation')
    while meshcat.GetButtonClicks(start_sim_button) < 1:
        time.sleep(1.0)

    # Replace the start button with a stop button
    meshcat.DeleteButton(start_sim_button)
    stop_sim_button = 'Stop Simulation'
    meshcat.AddButton(stop_sim_button)

    # Wait until the stop button is pressed before stopping the simulation
    print(f'Press the \'{stop_sim_button}\' to stop the simulation')

    # Add simulation monitors
    ...

    while meshcat.GetButtonClicks(stop_sim_button) < 1:
        # Advance the simulation
        t = simulator.get_context().get_time()
        simulator.AdvanceTo(t + 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The realtime rate isn't adaptive. It takes a wall clock reading at simulation time 0, and then just does the (sim_time_now - sim_time_origin) / (wall_clock_now - wall_clock_origin) division. If your "origin time" point is not calibrated correctly, it won't work the way you intend.

The call to `simulator.Initialize()` is what establishes the "origin time" correspondence between simulator time==0.0 and the current system wall clock at the time of Initialize.

Either don't call Initialize until you're about to start simulating (advancing), or else call it *again* just before you start simulating (advancing).